# presenting view controller on top of uiwindow subviews

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiview, uiwindow

I'm trying to create a intro screens using the MYBlurIntroductionView which is a UIView. As I want it on top of everything. I'm making it a subview of UIWindow.

```
UIWindow* currentWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
[currentWindow addSubview:self.introView];
```

Now i want to present a ViewController on top of it. I can present it on top of the active view controller. But it will be behind the introView. How can I get the presenting view controller above the intro view?

Answer (score -1):

First, add your mainVC to rootVC and then add your introView onto that mainVC as a subView. Later, as your introView is done then you could simply remove it from superView( mainVC ) ,and there you have your mainVC to be presented to your user. So no need to add introView to current as subview and then again adding mainVC to current.